# Using the White Checkmark accessory when row not selected

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView which enables multiple selection of rows.  I am using the CheckMark accessory to indicate selected rows and also a gradient background.

When I tap a cell the UITableView shows it as selected with the blue gradient and a white checkmark, but when i let go of the tap the checkmark accessory goes to a dark blue colour.

My question is does anyone know how I can get a white checkmark rather than the blue one.

The reason i need this is that for the selected rows I have a dark blue background and you cannot see the checkmark clearly.  I know I can create an image as the accessory view with a white checkmark which is fine, but I just wondered if there was a way to use the inbuilt white checkmark which appears when tapping a row?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. No cake for your question. you cant control the checkmark property color.
As you said only option is assign a Image with white checkmark in accessoryView property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make custom table view. So you can use any image for check mark.